# itextpdf overlapping long string

Tags: pdf, itext

Why is there overlapping text lines.

```
final String FONT = "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf";
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf=BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font (bf,14,Font.NORMAL);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(GetDn.displayName + "jsdgfjsdgfjkgsdkjfgkjafgjsdgf7239tf2fbjlsgfsdjgfskjdfakjsdg7sf9sdft9gABFLJGJSDJFG67TSD SDFJSDJFKGSDKJFG", font);
        document.add(chunk);
        document.close();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default height strings in chank is 0.
Height adjustment is done by adding code `chunk.setLineHeight(15);`

```
    final String FONT = "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf";
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 20,15);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));
    document.open();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font (bf,14,Font.NORMAL);
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(GetDn.displayName, font);
    chunk.setLineHeight(15);
    document.addAuthor(GetDn.displayName);
    document.addCreationDate();
    document.add(chunk);
    document.close();
```

[image]

Comment: If this solved your problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.